# How to remove space from the end of a line in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

The problem is the next, at the end of every line, the program writes a space. How to remove it?

```
public class Szorzotabla {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i ++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                System.out.print(i * j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

I expected the output of the multiplication table without space at the end of every line.

Comment: really unclear what you want the code to do, please elaborate with output examples

Comment: output looks like:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9*
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18*
* means no space at the end of every line.

Comment: You are printing a space at each iteration `i * j + " "`, so at the last iteration you will have an extra space. Maybe put each line to a string and at the end use `trim()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way :

```
String space;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i ++) {
    space = ""; // declare a variable here
    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.print(space + i * j); // and note here to change the order
        space = " "; // after the first iteration set a space to the variable
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to solve this.  One of the cleaner solutions might be to use Java's built-in ability to join Strings (added in Java 8, if I recall).

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    String[] products = new String[9];
    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        products[j-1] = String.valueOf(j * i);
    }
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", products));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a space at the end of the line because you're printing a space at the end of every `i*j` even though you don't need one for the last one of each line.

Instead, you can change it so that you print the space *before* `i*j`, and manually print the first `i*j` without a space before you enter the inner loop. This way your code remains relatively clean.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i ++) {
    System.out.print(i);
    for(int j = 2; j < 10; j++) { //start j at 2
        System.out.print(" " + i * j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(i * j + ( j < 9 ? " ", "" ));
```

when j is less than 9 (last) concat space else concat empty –